# Google App Engine Endpoints with Maven

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, maven-3, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm having trouble using the Google's Cloud endpoints with Android. I have one maven project, with two modules, Android app and Web app. The web app is generating the endpoints client library, but it's just a zip file with all the dependencies and the .jar file with complied classes and some pom file.

The problem is, how to make it included in the Android module? I need this in order to get the build fully automatized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used is to extract the zip file, and from within that extract the sources.jar to your Android project's src/main/java directory. You can write a script that does this such as the following. Maybe someone knows a better way.

```
CLIENTTMP=/tmp/android-client
LIBNAME=helloworld
VER=v1
LIBZIP=${LIBNAME}-${VER}-java.zip
SRCJAR=${CLIENTTMP}/${LIBNAME}/*jar
ANDROIDSRC=../MyAndroidModule/src/main/java

rm -rf ${CLIENTTMP}
mkdir -p ${CLIENTTMP}

# -o == overwrite w/o asking
# -d == output dir
unzip -o -d ${CLIENTTMP} ${LIBZIP}
unzip -o -d ${ANDROIDSRC} ${SRCJAR}
```

Comment: And does this work with Maven? I did it the way I manually pull all I need and I've created two submodules which I maintain/replace the code in.

Comment: Sure it works with Maven in the sense that the generated Android client libs are being unzipped into the src/java folder as if they're a regular part of my Android app's source. There is no formal maven dependency link between the web app and the client app, but I didn't necessarily need that.

Comment: I see what you mean. That sounds good. Only if it was platform independent :/ Probably writing a java .jar "script" that would do the  unzipping might work, right?